# Why does lavaan in SEM do a z test instead of t test for beta?

Tags: structural-equation-modeling

I've been learning about SEM and I was curious why lavaan uses the z test for testing a beta? I was reading here https://tdjorgensen.github.io/SEM-in-Ed-compendium/ch2.html that it was because estimators in SEM assume asymptotic normality and degrees of freedom are hard to calculate? Why can't we just use the same degrees of freedom from a regular linear regression.

Below I have examples of the same two models one in lavaan and the other in base R.

Base simple regression:

```
lm(Petal.Length ~ Petal.Width, data = iris) |> 
  summary()
```

```
#> 
#> Call:
#> lm(formula = Petal.Length ~ Petal.Width, data = iris)
#> 
#> Residuals:
#>      Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max 
#> -1.33542 -0.30347 -0.02955  0.25776  1.39453 
#> 
#> Coefficients:
#>             Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
#> (Intercept)  1.08356    0.07297   14.85   <2e-16 ***
#> Petal.Width  2.22994    0.05140   43.39   <2e-16 ***
#> ---
#> Signif. codes:  0 '***' 0.001 '**' 0.01 '*' 0.05 '.' 0.1 ' ' 1
#> 
#> Residual standard error: 0.4782 on 148 degrees of freedom
#> Multiple R-squared:  0.9271, Adjusted R-squared:  0.9266 
#> F-statistic:  1882 on 1 and 148 DF,  p-value: < 2.2e-16
```

SEM regression:

```
library(lavaan)
#> Warning: package 'lavaan' was built under R version 4.3.2
#> This is lavaan 0.6-17
#> lavaan is FREE software! Please report any bugs.
data(iris)
sem("Petal.Length ~ 1 + Petal.Width", data = iris, ) |> 
  summary()
```

````
#> lavaan 0.6.17 ended normally after 1 iteration
#> 
#>   Estimator                                         ML
#>   Optimization method                           NLMINB
#>   Number of model parameters                         3
#> 
#>   Number of observations                           150
#> 
#> Model Test User Model:
#>                                                       
#>   Test statistic                                 0.000
#>   Degrees of freedom                                 0
#> 
#> Parameter Estimates:
#> 
#>   Standard errors                             Standard
#>   Information                                 Expected
#>   Information saturated (h1) model          Structured
#> 
#> Regressions:
#>                    Estimate  Std.Err  z-value  P(>|z|)
#>   Petal.Length ~                                      
#>     Petal.Width       2.230    0.051   43.679    0.000
#> 
#> Intercepts:
#>                    Estimate  Std.Err  z-value  P(>|z|)
#>    .Petal.Length      1.084    0.072   14.950    0.000
#> 
#> Variances:
#>                    Estimate  Std.Err  z-value  P(>|z|)
#>    .Petal.Length      0.226    0.026    8.660    0.000

```
````